# Trying to find a book about stolen fossils, reanimation, and robot dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification

I read a book a long time ago that I absolutely adored. Sadly I don't own the book and can't remember what it was called. I do remember some details though:

1. The book takes place in the 1800s
2. Dinosaur fossils have been stolen from a museum but nobody knows what happened
3. The fossils are smuggled by surgically replacing the femur of a man with one. The man is put into a kind of exoskeletal suit to keep him alive.
4. There is a scene where the main character is faced down by a robotic tyrannosaur. They describe the hot oil dripping from its mouth like saliva.
5. The book either takes place in England or America
6. The book is at least eleven years old
7. The book is a novel, with no pictures

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  About when was "a long time ago?"  Knowing approximately what year you read this can help us narrow it down.  Do you recall any details of the cover at all?  Check out the other [suggestions for good story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you remember any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: @DavidW That's about all the detail I can recall. I suppose I must have read it at most, eleven years ago. I can't recall the cover, sorry. But thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you remember how long the book was? Less than 100 pages? More than 200? Were there any illustrations?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It was a novel, no illustrations.

Comment: Could be https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/580446.Unnatural_History, set in a Steampunk Victorian universe but not the actual 1800's so just a comment for now.  Will try to add answer when not on mobile....

Comment: It could be, keeping people alive via steampunk machinery sounds familier

Comment: I have the first three Pax Brittania books but I cannot find any mention of fossils being stolen or robot tyrannosaurs dripping hot oil.

Comment: @JohnRennie It's probably not it then. The books sound cool so I might end up reading them.

Comment: the cover had a metal t rex skeleton on it. can't remember the name though.